# save state of $_POST['username'] in PHP

Tags: php, session

How to save the state of `$_POST['username']` in PHP. I made a form to login, that form posts to MySql but it also posts to the users page, how to save that state of the user-page so when te user goes to another page the the state wil still be saved until you log in again.

Comment: You need to use PHP's sessions : http://www.tizag.com/phpT/phpsessions.php

Comment: Bit vague but I think you searching for `SESSION`.

Comment: thanks, i am going to try this.

Comment: Look into [sessions](http://php.net/manual/en/features.sessions.php)

Comment: Sounds to me like you need to read up on [Session Handling in PHP](http://php.net/manual/en/features.sessions.php).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use Sessions to store it. Find about it [here](http://php.net/manual/en/features.sessions.php). Use it like below.

set it like below,

```
session_start();
$_SESSION['username'] = $_POST['username'];
```

get that back at another page as

```
session_start();
$username = $_SESSION['username'];
```

Answer (score 2):

You want to look in to [sessions](http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.sessions.php)

Answer (score 1):

Use sessions. This link will provide you with all the information you need: http://php.net/manual/en/features.sessions.php

Answer (score 1):

A good way to do this is using sessions in PHP. you can save all kind of information you want and it will be accessible during the session

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

1. [PHP Sessions](http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.sessions.php) or
2. [Cookies](http://php.net/manual/en/features.cookies.php)

Answer (score 1):

Insert value in your query with variable $username = $_POST['username'];

You can get value with $_POST and $_REQUEST on another page.
If you post data with form action to another page then you dont need to use session .
and if you want to pass value with session first start session on page session_start().and put in $_SESSION['userName'] = $_POST['username']; and another page you can get value .first start session session_start();  and then $userName = $_SESSION['userName'];

echo $userName; it should be print the value.